# WEBGL - How to display an image?

Tags: javascript, webgl

i'm looking to just simply display an image on the canvas at x and y co-ordinates using WEBGL but have no clue how to do it. do i need to include shaders and all that stuff? i've seen code to display images but they are very bulky. I do not wish to use a framework. If possible could you comment and explain what the important sections do? I will be using WEBGL for a 2d tile based game.

thankyou for your time

Comment: have you looked at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebGL/Using_textures_in_WebGL they have some simple/short examples to use an image in webGL.

Comment: thats for drawing onto a moving cube though and is really difficult to get my head around

Comment: [Here's a tutorial on images in WebGL](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing.html) and one on [reproducing `canvas.drawImage` in WebGL](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-drawimage.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need a vertex and fragment shader, but they can be relatively simple. I'd recommend to start from the Mozilla example, as suggested by Ido, and after you got it running, remove the 3D aspect. In particular, you don't need the uMVPMatrix and uPmatrix, and your coordinate array can be 2D. For the vertex shader, that means:

```
attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;  
attribute vec2 aTextureCoord;  

varying highp vec2 vTextureCoord;  

void main(void) {  
  gl_Position = vec4(aVertexPosition, 0.0, 1.0);  
  vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;  
}
```